# How to convert natural language lines (without markers) into topics (starting with `+`) in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have the following text in an org file:

```
* Tasks

bla bla bla
cla cla cla
dla dla dla
ela ela ela
fla fla fla
gla gla gla
```

I would like to have:

```
* Tasks

+ bla bla bla
+ cla cla cla
+ dla dla dla
+ ela ela ela
+ fla fla fla
+ gla gla gla
```

Comment: Not sure if the title of the question is good. I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the region and use `C-c -` which is bound to `org-ctrl-c-minus`. That's one of the context-dependent bindings in Org mode: depending on where it is executed, it does different things. The doc string says:

> Insert separator line in table or modify bullet status of line.
> Also turns a plain line or a region of lines into list items.
> Calls ‘org-table-insert-hline’, ‘org-toggle-item’, or
> ‘org-cycle-list-bullet’, depending on context.

The second sentence describes the action here: it calls `org-toggle-item` whose doc string in turn says:

> Convert headings or normal lines to items, items to normal lines.
> If there is no active region, only the current line is considered.
>
> If the first non blank line in the region is a headline, convert
> all headlines to items, shifting text accordingly.
>
> If it is an item, convert all items to normal lines.
>
> If it is normal text, change region into a list of items.
> With a prefix argument ARG, change the region in a single item.

To change the bullets from `-` to `+`, go to one of the hyphens and say `C-u C-c -` : that's another use of `org-ctrl-c-minus` which ends up calling `org-cycle-list-bullet` on the whole list. If you keep repeating, you'll cycle through the sequence `-  + N. N)` for the Nth item if the sequence. See the doc string of `org-cycle-list-bullet` for the details.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant and general solution is to use rectangles. Select the region (notice that the start and end positions do matter), run `string-rectangle` (bound to `C-x r t`) and provide the string (in this case `+` ).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with an intermediate hacky step.

First, I converted everything into a comment, using `comment-dwim` which results in:

```
# bla bla bla
# cla cla cla
# dla dla dla
# ela ela ela
# fla fla fla
# gla gla gla
```

Then, I used `query-replace` to convert from `#` to `+`. After answering "yes" for all, I have the desired result:

```
+ bla bla bla
+ cla cla cla
+ dla dla dla
+ ela ela ela
+ fla fla fla
+ gla gla gla
```

However, Emacs (org-mode included) is a fantastic tool. There must be a better way to do this.